# Rank of Néron-Severi Group of $\mathbb P^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

What is the rank of the Néron-Severi group of $\mathbb P^2$ and what would be a basis for it?

Comment: Please add more context or details or there is a risk the question will be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $h^{0,1}(\mathbb{P}^2) = 0$ we have $\mbox{Pic}(\mathbb{P}^2) \cong \mbox{NS}(\mathbb{P}^2)$. We already know that $\mbox{Pic}(\mathbb{P}^2) = \mathbb{Z}\langle \mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(1)\rangle$. So the Néron-Severi group has rank 1 with basis $c_1(\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(1))$.

Comment: @Aetos: what you are told is true, but your question and this answer are about $\mathbf P^2$.